# Annotation Processing Compilation Steps

Tags: java, annotations

I read in this article(https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/01/how-to-process-java-annotations.html) that Annotation Processing has multiple rounds:

> Annotation processing happens in separate stages, called rounds. During each round, a processor gets a chance to process the annotations it is interested in.
>
> The annotations to process and the elements they are present on are available via the RoundEnvironment parameter passed into the process() method.
>
> If annotation processors generate new source or class files during a round, then the compiler will make those available for processing in the next round. This continues until no more new files are generated.
>
> The last round contains no input, and is thus a good opportunity to release any resources the processor may have acquired.

Can someone explain to my what it means by rounds? So for example let's say we have an annotation `Metrics.java`, when the compiler is parsing through the java source code it will first find all the elements that use this annotation and then at the end of compilation run the annotation process for that specific `Metrics` annotation where the `RoundEnvironment` passed in will contain all the elements that have the `Metrics` annotation?

Or anytime the compiler sees a annotation it will immediately run the annotation if it has a retention type of `Class` or `Source`. Otherwise it will not run the annotation for that annotation until runtime since it has a retention type of `Runtime`?

Comment: As far as I understand, the compiler never sees the annotations.  They are processed by annotation processors before the compiler sees them.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand, while parsing a java file compiler gathers all annotations seen in it then goes for processing them using  an annotation processor that we already prepared(first round).suppose  annotation processor  creates a new source file(.java) and has used annotation in it,here compiler goes for parsing that file and gathering its annotations then goes for processing them using annotation processors(second round).and this continue until in last java file(which created via annotation processor or not) we have no annotation in it.
and annotation processing is a part of javac that we should ask for enabling it(that we have some ways depend on environment like maven, command line, IDEs, and so on).
annotation processing doesn't run immediately by meeting first annotation in the source file and Retention policy isn't matter too.